# I need to deduct a year (lets say 1991) from 2015, using c#

Tags: c#, timespan

I've been looking all over for hours for a solution to this seriously simple code. I started my programming career yester day and got Visual Studio today. I have attempted to play with the "Hello World" excercises however deducting the two year from eachother became more difficult than i thought.

my code does show the level i am on  at the moment, and I am begging you guys, what the heck am I doing wrong?

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

            Console.Write("Please enter your first name: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Please enter your last name: ");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("You're Name is: " + firstName + " " + lastName);

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your birthyear");

            Console.WriteLine("");
            string yob = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Today it's...");

            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;   // Use current time.    
            string format = "yyyy";   // Use this format. (MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy)
            Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format)); // Write to console.
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Which means that you are approximately....");

            Console.WriteLine("?? Years old");

            //timespan between `datenow` and `date1`

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: convert yob  to datetime then do this:DateTime.Now.Year-Convertedyob.year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // get current time
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    // get year of birth from user
    String myYear = Console.ReadLine();

    // construct a DateTime from that year
    DateTime my = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt16(myYear), 1, 1);

    // devide by 365 and convert to int
    Console.Write(Convert.ToInt16((now - my).TotalDays) / 365);
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert `yob` to an int:

```
int yearOfBirth = int.Parse(yob); //This could fail! See note below
```

Then subtract it from today's year:

```
int yearsOld = DateTime.Now.Year - yearOfBirth;
Console.WriteLine(yearsOld + " years old");
```

Note: The `int.Parse` command could fail if you enter something that isn't a number, such as `two thousand`. Look into [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle that situation.

Comment: Wow thank you for the fast respose .. :) Although I still seem to have some problems.
As I understood, you wanted me to add a new line

           `String yob = Console.ReadLine();
            int.Parse yob = int.Parse(yob);`

I'm given an error when I attempt as you said and honestly, I am not really 100% sure of how the command `int` functions.. :(

Comment: `int` is a datatype, and you use it to declare a variable of that type. The command should be `int yearOfBirth = int.Parse(yob)`. That command says "declare a variable of type int named yearOfBirth, and set it's value to the result of int.Parse(yob)".

Answer (score 0):

System.TimeSpan will help you calculate the difference. 
A quick search for "difference in dates c#" got me this code. There are multiple methods on the page if you would like to learn more. Please let me know if you need more help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Console_DateTime
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.DateTime dtTodayNoon = new System.DateTime(2006, 9, 13, 12, 0, 0);
            System.DateTime dtTodayMidnight = new System.DateTime(2006, 9, 13, 0, 0, 0);
            System.TimeSpan diffResult = dtTodayNoon.Subtract(dtYestMidnight);
            Console.WriteLine("Yesterday Midnight - Today Noon = " + diffResult.Days);
            Console.WriteLine("Yesterday Midnight - Today Noon = " + diffResult.TotalDays);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/DateDiff_CS_DC09132006172429PM/DateDiff_CS_DC.aspx)

EDIT: Forgot top line of explanation.